# How to put score of first bash variable into second?

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-cli

I'm trying to write two variables in bash. First variable:

```
variable1=$(az monitor log-analytics workspace get-shared-keys \ 
--resource-group test --workspace-name test-workspace)
```

and the result:

```
{
  "primarySharedKey": "aaa",
  "secondarySharedKey": "bbb"
}
```

In second variable i need to grab primarySharedKey. I was trying something like that:

```
variable2=$variable1.primarysharedkey
```

but the result is giving me not only the value :

```
.primarysharedkeyKey": "aaa"
```

How to acomplish this to get only "aaa" value ?

Comment: bash doesn't parse JSON automatically. Use the `jq` utility.

Comment: @Mski : Your assignment actually sets `variable2` to the content of `variable1`, with the string `.primarysharedkey`, as you can easily test it by doing a `x=abc; z=$x.u; echo $z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
variable2=$(awk '{ print $2 }' <<<"$(echo $variable1)")
```

Comment: It works but I should youse print  $3 to get the value of presharedkey : 

variable2=$(awk '{ print $3 }' <<<"$(echo $variable1)")